# plotly.js not displaying anything on my own website

Tags: javascript, html, plotly

So I've been trying to use the plotly.js to plot a graph that I need for my website...however I do not know why it's not working..? It creates the space where the graph should go but it's not showing anything... the website itself for plotly.js has a "Getting started" page and I followed but it's not working.. any ideas why? here is the code withing the script tags and also here is the bit of code where I am actually trying to create the graph (This is in HTML)

```
<script>
    TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');
    Plotly.plot( TESTER,[{
        x: [1,2,3,4,5],
        y: [1,2,4,8,16] }], {
        margin: {t: 0}
    });

</script>

<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <div id="logo_text">
                <!-- class="logo_colour", allows you to change the colour of the text -->
                <h1><a href="index.html">Sensor Data Graphs<span class="logo_colour"> </span></a></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="site_content">
        <div id="content">
            <!-- Page Content starts here -->
            <!--Heading-->
            <h2><b>Graphs</b></h2>
            <div id="tester" style="width:90%;height:250px;"></div>
```

Comment: If you have the script in exactly that position, the element "tester" doesn't exist yet when you try to get a reference to it. Move the script to the end of the page.

Comment: ...I can't believe that was the mistake...why did I think of putting the script at the beginning I have no idea. Not even wanting to load it before I create the area. Well thank you very much you're a lifesaver :)